# How to fix missing library after update of Homebrew

Tags: python, fortran, homebrew, dylib, dyld

I'm trying to install a program on my mac. There is one step intends to Compile Fortran modules, when I run the scripts I got an error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libxar.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I checked the directory and there is only `libicui18n.65.dylib` here. So how can I install the old version or can I make the program to use the latest version.

Best regards